# Creating a Scrolling Categories Section In a Navigation Controller (XCode)

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbar, categories, uinavigationcontroller

So I'm curious. I was looking into a way to create a categories selector similar to the one located at the top of this application: [http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xfeed-rss-reader/id313206921?mt=8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh8kY.jpg) ... 06921?mt=8. Would I tackle this using a Toolbar and elongating it to where the user can 'scroll' side to side for categories? Or a ScrollView with a Tabbar in it? I want to do this the 'proper' way per say and I've seen flags raised about a Tabbar being in a ScrollView.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I were implementing this, I would create it with a UIScrollView containing UIButtons. UITabBars have some nice integration with UIViewControllers and UINavigationControllers, but the benefits quickly drop off when you need more customizable behavior (left to right scrolling, for instance.). I would normally just put them all in a xib and connect the outlets appropriately, unless it was important that they be dynamic.

You mentioned correctness, so an even more "correct" way is to create a UIControl similar to a UISegmentedControl that handles the creation of properly sized labels, deals with touches appropriately, etc. If you are setting categories dynamically you'll want to override sizeThatFits: and call sizeToFit so you can properly size the content area of your scrollview.

Comment: I was also thinking about this method. I'm not sure how complicated it will get as I haven't tackled it yet... but once I hit this point, I will definitely give the UIButton method a shot first. Next will be the UIControl method!

Comment: If its a one off object, just put the buttons in a xib. If it needs to be reusable, than the UIControl is probably the way to go.

Comment: I always tend to manually create my stuff via code anyways. I try to avoid xib files and storyboards at all cost.